# How to Ignore/bypass debugger stop at errors in try block

Tags: xcode, try-catch, exc-bad-access

I want **not** to stop debugger at try block in Xcode5.
just looking something like (ignore this line/ignore debugger at this line if any error occurs)

```
@try {
    //this line sometimes throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS error
    a = [object1 isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]];
}
@catch(NSException *ex)
{
    continue;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to stop on an exception, deactivate your global Exceptions breakpoint.

Comment: I didnt add any global Exceptions breakpoint.
Q1: is it enabled by default ? if so how can I remove ?
Q2: or should I add a global Exceptions breakpoint and should I disable it ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! EXC_BAD_EXCESS is not an exception. It is fatal. Your code is not "stopping in the debugger". You are crashing.